# Unable to find user data from a windows 10 (home) disk using Knoppix

Tags: windows, knoppix

Wife's laptop no longer boots after a failed windows (home x64) 10 update--bluescreen.   I'm able to boot it with a Knoppix live USB thumbdrive.  However when I mount the ntfs filesystem holding C:, I only see Default, Public, and desktop.ini in what would have been c:\Users.

I've also tried a few searches using find in that filesystem for keywords of files/directories she would have had with out any luck.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction of where it might be hiding?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you should really be asking this at a windows site ... they may be able to help you find the location where your files are stored

Comment: Could you show exactly what you see?